# Springs Qualifier error

Tags: java, spring

I'm learning Springs and while learning `@Autowiring`, came across `@Qualifier`. I've declared a qualifier but still there is an Exception thrown.

Below is my Code

**Spring.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


    <bean id="pointA" class="org.xyz.practice.Point">
        <qualifier value="myCircle" />
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="${pointA.pointX}"></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="${pointA.pointY}"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="pointB" class="org.xyz.practice.Point">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="${pointA.pointX}"></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="${pointA.pointY}"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations" value="configurations.properties"></property>
    </bean>



    <bean id="circle" class="org.xyz.practice.Circle">

    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />


</beans>
```

**Circle.java:**

```java
package org.xyz.practice;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;

public class Circle implements Shape {

    private Point center;

    public Point getCenter() {
        return center;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myCircle")
    public void setCenter(Point center) {
        this.center = center;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Drawing a circle...");
        System.out.println("Circle point si (" + center.getX() + " , " + center.getY() + ")");
    }

}
```

**MainClass:**

```java
package org.xyz.practice;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class DrawingApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        Shape shape = (Shape) context.getBean("circle");
        shape.draw();
    }

}
```

**Exception:**

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'circle': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setCenter' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [org.xyz.practice.Point] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: pointA,pointB; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.xyz.practice.Point] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: pointA,pointB
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'circle': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setCenter' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [org.xyz.practice.Point] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: pointA,pointB; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.xyz.practice.Point] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: pointA,pointB
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:647)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at org.xyz.practice.DrawingApp.main(DrawingApp.java:10)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.xyz.practice.Point] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: pointA,pointB
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveNotUnique(DependencyDescriptor.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    ... 15 more
```

Please don't mark this as a duplicate of `@Resource`(related) question, I want to go step-by-step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete the Spring context configuration via xml by adding to the Circle bean the center property.

```
<bean id="circle" class="org.xyz.practice.Circle">
    <property name="center" class="package.Point"/>
</bean>
```

You are also not using the @Annotation configuration, try not to mix xml and @Annotation configuration. If you want to use that configuration, add a component-scan to your applicationContext.xml.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="base.package.to.scan" />
```

Comment: Hi friend, this worked fine for me, but the tutorials where I referred, this wasn't mentioned, Can you please let me know what is happening?

Comment: In here you tell Spring explicitly, which one of 2 existing points do you want to pass into your `Circle`. Using XML. If you don't use XML, but use annotations, then you need `Qualifier` to somehow pick one. Or you can use `@Primary` annotation of Spring.

Comment: Spring offers 2 ways to configure it XML and @Annotation. With the first one, the hole configuration is written in XML(s) files (one or more); with the second one you use '@Annotations' ('@Autowire', '@Qualifier', '@Service', ...) to configure beans and a 'component-scan' to scan for beans in your code. In your code you are not enabling '@Annotation' because nothing tells Spring to scan the packages and look for them.

Answer (score 0):

Put qualifier at your parameter:

```
@Autowired
public void setCenter(@Qualifier("myCircle") Point center) {
    this.center = center;
}
```

Comment: The `@Qualifier` annotation is [specified](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) as being able to annotate a field, method, parameter (and others). Why would putting it on the parameter make any difference here? What makes you think so?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis My experience with Spring injection and `Qualifier` annotations.

Comment: I'd like to trust your experience, but I need more. For example, if you try to run their code with the change you propose, it makes absolutely no difference. That should've been part of your experience. The issue here is that they've registered a `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`, but no `QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver` to handle the `@Qualifier`.